# In Node.js PUT method how i can update a specific value from multiple handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, put, node-mongodb-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8nlU.png)

1. Here I update the value of quantity (-1) from a handler .
2. I want to add quantity from another handler.
3. now how can add new quantity from a input field by new handler which is in the same Api and same value?

Comment: Code for your question should be in plain text in your question, NEVER in images.  This is for a whole bunch of reasons such as people writing answers can copy/paste code into answers instead of having to retype it all, text can be indexed for searching, text is easier to read on mobile, etc...  Don't insert images of code here.  Please use the "edit" button to fix your question now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't recommend depending on the client to give you the actual quantity (See `updatedProduct.quantity - 1`) cause you can never trust it. I would fetch it first and see there is a product with that id and get the quantity from there, or even set the quantity using the `$inc operator`

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

I didn't understand questions number 2 and 3. Can you explain further?